# How to use a local computer visit a VPS' localhost:port website?

Tags: vps, vultr

Sorry that my English is not good.

I use this: https://github.com/playdog-io/healthy-ipolef-PQMM   established a dapp in my VPS, and it's running at the VPS' localhost:5000. I want to use my local computer to visit the dapp, so I visit  (the IP of my VPS):5000, but it didn't work. So can anyone tell me how to make it works?

the VPS is from vultr.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same issue with my python flask application

Comment: no, I didn't. I give up the project.